# Что означают сокращения наб. и гл/кр.?

Tags: сокращения

Что означают сокращения **наб.** и **гл/кр.** ?
Область - текстиль и трикотаж.

Примеры:

> ПЛЕД флис наб.
> ПЛЕД флис гл/кр.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я думаю, что ***наб.*** — набивной, а ***гл/кр*** — гладкокрашеный.

[набивно́й](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9)
2. Об узоре, рисунке, нанесённом на ткань; о ткани с таким узором, рисунком (нанесённым вручную или машинным способом). *Набивной сатин. Скатерть с набивным рисунком.*

[Гладкокрашеная ткань](https://textiletrend.ru/terminyi/gladkokrashenaya-tkan.html) — одноцветная.

Я открываю тяжелые шторы: набивная плотная ткань на бежевой шелковой подкладке, рисунок ― темно-зеленые стебли и бархатно-пурпурные цветы. [А. И. Слаповский. 100 лет спустя. Письма нерожденному сыну (окончание) // «Волга», 2009]